# Output label shows only part of what I want to display

Tags: c#

I have this program that I am working on for class, I think the problem is in my if statements. When I run the program and make my selection and click the total button and I get this as a display "for your appetizer, for your entree, and for dessert" in the order label and the price for the steak dinner in the order total label. I think I may have to use switch statements, but I'm not sure any suggestions would be of great help, thanks.

```
 namespace Restaurant
 {
  public partial class frmRestaurant : Form
  {
    decimal AppetizerPrice = 0.0m;
    decimal EntreePrice = 0.0m;
    decimal DessertPrice = 0.0m;
    decimal total = 0.0m;
    string AppetizerOrder = "", EntreeOrder = "", DessertOrder = "", order = "";

    public frmRestaurant()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalculateTotal();
        Order();
        lblOrder.Text = order;
        lblTotal.Text = total.ToString();
    }

    private void grpAppetizer_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radCheeseSticks.Checked)
        {
            AppetizerPrice = 5.99m;
            AppetizerOrder = "Cheese Sticks";
        }
        else if (radGarlicBread.Checked)
        {
            AppetizerPrice = 4.50m;
            AppetizerOrder = "Garlic Bread";
        }
        else if (radChipsnSalsa.Checked)
        {
            AppetizerPrice = 3.50m;
            AppetizerOrder = "Chips and Salsa";
        }
    }

    private void grpEntree_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radSteakDinner.Checked)
        {
            EntreePrice = 12.50m;
            EntreeOrder = "Steak Dinner";
        }
        else if (radChickenParm.Checked)
        {
            EntreePrice = 10.99m;
            EntreeOrder = "Chicken Parmigiana";
        }
        else if (radChipsnSalsa.Checked)
        {
            EntreePrice = 3.50m;
            EntreeOrder = "Chips and Salsa";
        }
    }

    private void grpDessert_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radSteakDinner.Checked)
        {
            DessertPrice = 12.50m;
            DessertOrder = "Steak Dinner";
        }
        else if (radChickenParm.Checked)
        {
            DessertPrice = 10.99m;
            DessertOrder = "Chicken Parmigiana";
        }
        else if (radChipsnSalsa.Checked)
        {
            DessertPrice = 3.50m;
            DessertOrder = "Chips and Salsa";
        }
    }

    public decimal CalculateTotal()
    {
        total = AppetizerPrice + EntreePrice + DessertPrice;
        return total;
    }

    public string Order()
    {
        order = AppetizerOrder + "for your appetizer," + EntreeOrder + "for your        entree, and " + DessertOrder + "for dessert";
        return order;
    }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [`GroupBox.Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) event is not useful for your use case. The enter event is invoked sometime during the control activation, but not when the value is changed.

One way to fix your problem is to set the appetizer/entree/dessert price and text only when the "Total" button is clicked. You do not need it before that in the current form right now.

Another way to fix it is to use the correct event: Just handle the [`RadioButton.CheckedChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx) event for all of those radio buttons, for example:

```
private void radGarlicBread_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radGarlicBread.Checked)
    {
        AppetizerPrice = 4.50m;
        AppetizerOrder = "Garlic Bread";
    }   
}
```

Comment: I changed the event handler and made some other changes, the program runs and calculates the total. It may not be pretty but it does work, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you probably want to use `String.Format()`, because it'll look a bit cleaner than a bunch of concatenation--it'll also help you catch things like the lack of spaces here (your output seems like it would be, e.g. 'Chips and Salsafor your appetizer...')

It might also be better to just find whichever item is checked in the `Order` method rather than update it every time the user checks.

I'm not sure what is wrong, but maybe you can do a `Debug.WriteLine()` every time each of the `Enter()` methods is called to see what is going on.

For example:

```
Debug.WriteLine("grpDesert_Enter");
Debug.WriteLine(radSteakDinner.Checked);
Debug.WriteLine(radChickenPark.Checked);
Debug.WriteLine(radChipsnSalsa.Checked);
```